# Linux: Checking if VSync is active or not

Tags: linux, video, display

How do I check if **VSync** is enabled on my Linux (Debian) system?

```
glxinfo | grep "VSync"
```

gives no result. Is there another command? I'm not playing games and only rarely experience tearing when watching, i.e. youtube videos.

Comment: Run `glxgears`. If vsync is enabled you would be getting 60fps, the current refresh rate of the monitor. If the number is higher, then you don't have vsync.